# cambiar url de imagen con texto puesto en un form

Tags: html

no encuentro como pero básicamente quiero hacer que haya un FORMa y abajo una imagen,
la imagen por ejemplo imagen.png y que si pones dentro del FORMa "hola" cambie imagen.png a hola.png.
y que abajo en la imagen muestre la imagen que se llame hola.png

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes hacer utilizando React

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  // Creamos una variable de estado para guardar el texto del formulario
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  // Creamos una función para manejar el cambio de texto en el formulario
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    // Actualizamos el estado con el nuevo texto
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  // Creamos una variable para guardar el nombre de la imagen
  const imageName = text ? `${text}.png` : "imagen.png";

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>
          Escribe algo:
          <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        </label>
      </form>
      <img src={imageName} alt="Imagen" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```